# Setup JUnit, Mockito in LibGdx (Kotlin)

Tags: kotlin, libgdx, junit5

I'm trying to setup unit tests in the new LibGdx project. 
I added dependencies to `:core` project:

```
project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "kotlin"
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

    dependencies {
        // ...

        testImplementation "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.6.1"
        testRuntimeOnly "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.6.1"
        testImplementation "com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2:mockito-kotlin:2.2.0"
        kaptTest "org.mockito:mockito-core:3.3.3"
        kaptTest "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$daggerVersion"
    }
```

Test folder: `core/src/test/kotlin/`

Test class:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test

class FirstTest {
    @Test
    fun `my first test`() {
        assertEquals(1,1)
    }
}
```

But I got error: `Unresolved reference: junit`

What I'm doing wrong?

P.S.: I'm trying run tests in IntelliJ IDEA

**[ EDIT ]**

Link to repo test branch: https://github.com/Alcadur/libgdx-not-working-tests

Comment: Did you set the test source set in your module gradle script? Something like `sourceSets.test.java.srcDirs += "src/test/kotlin"` should be set, otherwise gradle can't know where `testImplementation` applies.

Comment: Since you only show part of your Gradle file you might be missing ˋuseJUnitPlatformˋ in your test task.

Comment: I apply changes you suggest but it not helps, I add full gradle.build to question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution for my problem ([full article](https://blog.noynoy.org/setting-up-kotlin-junit-mockito-gitlab-ci-for-libgdx-projects/))

I have to replace

```
sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = [ "src/" ]
sourceSets.test.java.srcDirs = [ "test" ]
```

to

```
sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = [ "src/main/java/" ]
sourceSets.test.java.srcDirs = [ "src/test/java/" ]
```

I also update repo for this question: [GitHub repo](https://github.com/Alcadur/libgdx-not-working-tests)